# Pandas - apply function to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are two columns in my dataframe.
One is called `brand name`,another is `total amount`
[image]

I defined a function to determine that:

```
if the brand name == 'something' and total amount > 'some number'
then return 'something'
```

I want to apply the function to dataframe - `df[["Brand Name","Total amount"]]` and it return errors.

Please advise how to solve this problem?Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use image as input example.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Can you show your function for determining `something` and `total amount > 'some number'`?. Also, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What errors are you getting? How did you define the function? How did you try to apply it to those two columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You function should look something like this:

```
def func_name(x):
    if x['Brand Name'] == 'something' and x['total amount'] > y:
        return 'some'
```

Use:

```
df.apply(func_name, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't need a function. `pandas` provides you options to `filter` the dataset:

```
df[(df[brand name] == 'something') & (df[total amount] > 'some number')]
```